# Modify Bluetooth plist DeviceCache and retain changes?

Tags: mac, macos, bluetooth

I was following this page: [Anyone able to connect gioteck VX-1 (PS3 controller) via Bluetooth?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75889/anyone-able-to-connect-gioteck-vx-1-ps3-controller-via-bluetooth/75899#75899?newreg=6d175b400e5f442d964e238aa8f7c98a) to modify the bluetooth plist settings on my Mac to allow a Chinese PS3 controller to work with my Mac.

Specifically, I was trying to change the ClassOfDevice and Services. Because from what I can tell, the Chinese PS3 controllers are fully functional, they just don’t have the ClassOfDevice and Services stored in their Bluetooth chips. Thus my Mac thinks the device isn’t functional.

Unfortunately, Mavericks seems to wipe out any changes I make to the plist as soon as I try to connect the controller over Bluetooth.

Does anyone know how to retain the changes to the Bluetooth Plist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer!

Mavericks caches preferences so you need to load your changes into Mavericks' cache.

The key is to do: defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist in terminal after making your changes to the bluetooth.plist and before turning bluetooth back on.

See here: https://github.com/OpenEmu/OpenEmu/issues/1041#issuecomment-39808894 for a full writeup.

Comment: Hello @MrRocketman, I’m in a similar situation however your solution didn’t work for me. Even after restarting the BT service, after turning on the controller (‘P3’ button) it appears as a keyboard in the BT preferences and OpenEmu won’t see it as a controller. How did you come up with the right value for the ‘Services’ data?

Comment: The 'services' data was pulled from the link in my original post: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75889/anyone-able-to-connect-gioteck-vx-1-ps3-controller-via-bluetooth/75899#75899?newreg=6d175b400e5f442d964e238aa8f7c98a which came from a real PS3 controller. I never had problems with my showing up as a keyboard instead. I just struggled getting Mavericks to utilize the changes I had made to the plist. Did you verify that the 'services' field was the same after you turned BT back on?

Comment: Alright, I found the problem. Please see this https://github.com/OpenEmu/OpenEmu/issues/1041#issuecomment-39808894 for an updated writeup.

Comment: Damn! Too little too late, I returned the controller and bought an original one instead :) anyways, thank you and keep up the good work!