# MacBook Air recognises PS3 controller as keyboard (10.14)

Tags: macos, mojave, bluetooth

I got a new controller and I wanted to connect it to my mac. But when I connect it, it either (a): prompts me to type a passcode on the controller, (b): connects as a keyboard, or (c): fails to connect and has a options button which opens the actual passcode box (0000), but doesn‘t do anything, or (d): connects properly, but the sticks and buttons don‘t work. I've tried [this solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75889/anyone-able-to-connect-gioteck-vx-1-ps3-controller-via-bluetooth?newreg=be03e55190e74baabc6d273448c144a6), but it doesn‘t fix the sticks. My other controller (the one that came with the ps3) works perfectly, and I can use all inputs on that one. I'm assuming my new one is a real-deal controller based on the model number (though it is different from my other controller).

Does anyone have any solutions?